# Is it possible to execute a script when a user downloads a file through SFTP?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-20.04

I'm looking for a solution to receive an e-mail when a user on our machines downloads a group of files. I'm aware of the procedure to send the email, however, I'm not so sure about how to configure the machine to actually trigger the script. All of our systems use Ubuntu 20.04 at the moment.

Comment: The ftp daemon should already have access logs for this.

Comment: @Sherif Note that "sftp" has nothing to do with "ftp", and that `sshd` (which provides the `sftp` service) doesn't really provide those sort of file transfers logs.

Comment: Sure it does. You can configure sshd to log to syslog. Additionally openssh has its own log facility. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/74234/321771) for more details.

Comment: Hey y'all. Thanks for the speedy responses, appreciate it! I'm aware of the logging part configurable through sshd - where I'm lost at (or just ignorant of) is a way to *execute a script* when someone downloads a file - not log it to a file.